# Given $a_n, b_n$ are both convergent sequences such that $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, show $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Not sure if my proof as is is correct:

Since $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, we have $a_n - b_n \leq 0$. As such, by the limit location theorem it holds that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n - b_n) \leq 0$. By linearity, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n - \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n \leq 0$, which implies $lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$.

My one concern is using the LL Theorem on the sequence $a_n - b_n$: do I need to prove this sequence is convergent first?

Comment: If $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ (with $a,b$ finite), then $a_n-b_n \to a-b$. This is straightforward to show from the definition. Since $(-\infty,0]$ is closed, and $a_n-b_n \in (-\infty,0]$ for all $n$, we must have $a-b \in (-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 1):

So it amounts to prove that if $u_{n}\rightarrow u$ and $u_{n}\leq 0$, then $u\leq 0$.

Assume that $u>0$, consider the positive number $u/2$, then $|u_{n}-u|<u/2$ for large $n$, and hence $u_{n}>u-u/2=u/2>0$, contradicts the assumption that $u_{n}\leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)=a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} (b_n)$=b ,then using epsilon definition of limit and this property of real numbers:
$|a-b|\leq|a|+|b|$ you can prove easily that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n-b_n)=a-b,$

Then in order to prove the inequality above that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)$ prove first that for every $c<a$ it holds $\neg \lim_{n\to\infty} (b_n)=c$

Comment: Huh? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat what?

Comment: The wording is peculiar, to put it mildly. How does this address the OPs question of convergence?

Comment: @copper.hat is it better now?

Comment: Well, you are trying to show that $\lim_n b_n \neq c$, the negation of $\lim_n b_n = c$ could be interpreted as being a weaker statement. Plus, it is hard to read.

Comment: so how could I improve it?

Comment: Replace the negation by an explicit $\lim_n b_n \neq c$.